# Recursion problems in C

Tags: c, recursion, solver, anagram

I am working on an anagram solver in C. Hit a problem where the solver will return the first few anagrams correctly, however on ones that extend past 2 words, it begins to enter an infinite loop.

Example:

I enter "team sale rest" into the anagram solver, it responds with teamster ale, and a few others. Then when it arrives at releases, it enters an infinite loop where it prints "releases am matt" "releases am am matt" etc.

Here is the code base:

```
//recursively find matches for each sub-word
int findMatches(char string[], char found_so_far[])
{
    printf("String entering function: %s\n", string);
    int string_length = strlen(string);
    int_char_ptr *results = getPowerSet(string, string_length);
    if(!results)
        return 2;
    // selects length of subset, starting with the largest
    for (int i = string_length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        // iterates through all the subsets of a particular length
        for(int j = 0; j < results->count[i]; j++)
        {
            word_array *matches = NULL;
            // check words against dictionary
            matches = dictionary_check(results->table[i][j]);
            if (matches)
            {
                // iterate through matches
                for(size_t k = 0; k < matches->size; k++)
                {
                    int found_length;
                    // find out length of string needed for found
                    if (strcmp(found_so_far, "") == 0)
                        found_length = strlen(matches->arr[k]) + 1;
                    else
                        found_length = strlen(found_so_far) + strlen(matches->arr[k]) + 2;
                    char found[found_length];

                    // on first passthrough, copy directly from matches
                    if (strcmp(found_so_far, "") == 0)
                        strcpy(found, matches->arr[k]);
                    else
                        sprintf(found, "%s %s", found_so_far, matches->arr[k]);
                    char tempstr[string_length];
                    strcpy(tempstr, string);
                    char *remain = get_remaining_letters(tempstr, results->table[i][j]);
                    // if there are no letters remaining
                    if (strcmp(remain, "") == 0)
                    {
                        printf("MATCH FOUND: %s \n", found);
                        // alternatively, could store strings to array
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        findMatches(remain, found);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        free(results->table[i][results->count[i] - 1]);
        free(results->table[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How I read it (I am obviously missing something) is that it should try to match all matches, and if it can't , it should move to the next subset of letters found.

I have tries going through with a debugger, and cant make rhyme or reason of it.

Comment: This function calls things that may, in themselves, have bugs.  We don't have code for the things so, even if someone was inclined to try to debug for you, they could not.  You need to narrow down the problem area.  What did you find out during your own debugging?

Comment: Thanks Martin for your response. Definitely things I will keep in mind for next time I post! Of course as soon as I post this, I end up seeing the problem, after days of attempted debugging. get_remaining_letters used the original results->table[i][j] and removed the letters. This would leave an empty string for the next iteration and cause it to not perform as expected. Fixed by copying the string to a temporary one inside that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above in the commment:

get_remaining_letters used the original results->table[i][j] and removed the letters. This would leave an empty string for the next iteration and cause it to not perform as expected. Fixed by copying the string to a temporary one inside that function.